# Prove $[a],[b]\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $[a]=[a']$ and $[b]=[b']$ imply $[a]+[b]=[a+b]=[a'+b']=[a']+[b']$

Tags: proof-explanation, equivalence-relations, congruence-relations

Please see below for my partial proof. I'm stuck at the point where I've shown
$a+b=a'+nl+b'+nk$. If someone could help show how to complete this proof that would be great.

Suppose $[a],[b]\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $[a]=[a']$ and $[b]=[b']$. Aice adds $[a]$ and $[b]$ as $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$. Bob adds them as $[a']+[b']=[a'+b']$. Show that their answers are the same.

$Proof.$ Since $[a]=[a']$ we know that $a\equiv a'\pmod n$ and thus $a-a'=nl$ for some $l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly since $[b]=[b']$ we know that $b\equiv b'\pmod n$ and thus $b-b'=nk$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So then $a=a'+nl$ and $b=b'+nk$.

Then

$a+b=a'+nl+b'+nk$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a+b = a'+b' + (l+k)n$, we have $a+b = (a'+b') \pmod n$ and so
$a+n \sim a'+b'$.

Comment: So then since $a+b = a'+b' + (l+k)n$ we can show $(a+b)-(a'+b')=n(l+k)$. Thus $n\mid(a+b)-(a'+b')$. So then $a+b\equiv a'+b'\pmod n$ so $[a+b]=[a'+b']$. @copper.hat is my breakdown of this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.